# Linq to SQL distinct join and group

Tags: linq-to-sql

I've been struggling with this Linq query...
I have the following 2 tables:
1) EmailRunHeaders - with columns: Id, EmailRunId, EmailId
2) EmailTrackers - with columns: Id, EmailId

Every day a batch of emails are sent. A unique "EmailRunId" is assigned to a batch/group of emails and each email is assigned an "EmailId". This info is then stored in the "EMailHeaders" table.
So, each emailId in the table will be unique, but the EmailRunId will appear more than once..since there is more than one email in each "batch" or run.

When an email is opened, using a HTTP handler, the open is logged in the EmailTracker table...where the particular EmailId is then stored. Since an email could be opened more than once, it is possible that a EmailId could appear more than once in this table.

I need the total number of emails opened, without double counting emails opened more than once, for every email run.

This is what I have so far. The nested query works fine..returning the total number of emails opened for each run, but only if there where at least 1 opened for each run.
I then tried wrapping that in another join to return all the distinct EmailRunIds from the header table..but that is where I am stuck..I don't know how to get the EmailRunId from "ah1".

```
from arh1 in EmailRunHeaders.Select(x => x.EmailRunID).Distinct()
join eo in 
(from et in EmailTrackers
join arh2 in EmailRunHeaders
on et.EmailId equals arh2.EmailID.ToString() into j1
from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
group j2 by j2.EmailRunID
into g
select new {runId = g.Key, count = g.Count()})
on arh1 equals eo.runId into tg
from tg2 in tg.DefaultIfEmpty()
select tg2
```